# How to parent a bone to a bone on another armature

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I'm making a model with different sets of hair, so I want to the hairs to have separate armatures. The issue is how do I connect the armatures to the main one so the function properly. I tried using a child of constraint, but that moved the mesh into a different spot. What's the proper solution here?

Answer (score 1):

after adding the child constraint, click on "set inverse".

[image]